# How to navigate to a specific tab from tableviewcontroller ? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TableViewController embedded in a Tab bar controller. In the tableview controller I select a row and  it goes to  DetailedView controller.

How can I go back to my main TableViewController? I tried (perform segue with identifier) but it goes to the TableViewController  without displaying the tab bar at the bottom. I also tried to link the button with the main TabBarController but it goes to the first tab and not the tableView tab that want.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var window: UIWindow?

    @IBAction func backButton(sender: AnyObject) {
//        var vc : UIViewController?
//        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard( name: "Main", bundle: nil)
//        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController")


        performSegueWithIdentifier("goBack", sender: self)

//        
//        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
//        window?.rootViewController = vc
//        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.editing = true
    }
```

Comment: When you say "goes to DetailedView controller", what's the mechanism causing that to happen?

Comment: I used  func tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

Comment: And what code in that function causes the new controller to appear?

Comment: Thank you philip , I embdeed my TableViewController inside a navigation controller and it worked.  Code :                                                                      override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        switch indexPath.section {
            
        case 0 :

       performSegueWithIdentifier("detailedView1", sender: self)
        case 1:
            

            performSegueWithIdentifier("detailedView2", sender: self)
          
        
        default: break
        }
        

        
    }